# StackFlairWidget - OS X Dashboard widget for displaying flair(tm)

Tags: app, mac-os-x, widget, flair

### *Important*: BETA introductory version, lots more to come

### *Warning*: Beta version does not check empty responses, this version may not work for users without Area 51 accounts

---

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]
[image]

### About

A Mac OS X Dashboard widget for displaying flair(tm) for multiple associated accounts.

#### License

MIT License

#### Download

Beta 2:
http://stackflairwidget.googlecode.com/files/StackFlairWidget.wdgt-1.zip

#### Platform

Mac OS X only (atleast 10.4.3)

### Contact

Project Hosting at Google Code: http://code.google.com/p/stackflairwidget/

### Code

(not available currently) Dashcode Project - JavaScript + UI

Comment: looks great! one suggestion: make the badge numbers a bit bigger and perhaps white or darker white for the numbers?

Comment: thanks - I have redesigned that part to use HTML - so far this http://i.imgur.com/Pebst.png

Comment: yes looks much better!